# Salvaging Google Authenticator data from water damaged LG G5

Tags: broken-screen, google-authenticator, water-damage

I have an LG G5 that has water damage as well as a cracked screen. There is no guarantee that the water damage can be fixed. However, I have an app called Google Authenticator on that phone, and I need to transfer the app to my new phone that I will get.

I am thinking of getting a new LG G5, and I will use the same google account, would it then be possible to get my google authenticator app on the new phone aswell?

Is there anyway to get my google authenticator from 1 phone to the other?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if your question was more specific as to what services you authenticate with through Google Authenticator. Most services require you to have at least one "fallback method", normally something like a one-time code, or sending an SMS instead (Google has both of these, and more).

If you have a valid fall-back method, it is vastly easier to disable/re-enable this functionality instead of salvaging the app and its contents.

Furthermore, even if you could salvage the app contents, Google Authenticator has protections against migration between phones. This is a security feature of that specific app. If you don't like this (like me), you can use another app, for example [Authy](https://authy.com/) which syncs your 2FA-keys in the cloud.

In short, my recommendation is that you investigate resetting your 2FA instead, and if you wish, sync your keys with a cloud solution this time instead, to avoid this happening in the future.